# Injecting an object with nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer to specific pages

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I need to inject an object named "smth" to window on pages **with specific URLs** with nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer. Is there any way to implement this? It'll be ok if window.smth returns undefined on the other pages.

```
// currently
init: function(aWindow) {
    let self = this;
    let window = XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(aWindow);

    if (window.location.href !== pageURL) {
        return;
    }

    return {
            // ...
    }
}
```

Now window.smth returns XPCOM wrapped nsISupports object on the other pages :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it may be possible if at all with that approach, but you can at least listen for the "content-document-global-created" notification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#Documents and only inject the global

```
observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
    if (topic === 'content-document-global-created' && 
        subject instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow) {
        if (!subject.location.href.match(/http:\/\/example.com/)) {return;}
        XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(subject).myGlobal = {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this could solve the problem, but i'm afraid there might be some troubles with memory consumption or some security problems. I mean that we can set which props can be readable and which can be writable using nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer. And we can't do this using "content-document-global-created" XPCOM event (correct me if i'm not right). Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Try the following in place of the corresponding line in my answer: `Object.defineProperty(XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(subject), 'nonWritableGlobal', {writable:false, value:'myConstant'});` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty for usage. Mozilla used to use `__defineGetter__` which you might also try if the above does not work, but the latter was deprecated and the former should work.